# How do you get the max value from an elasticsearch field in Java plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm writing a custom scoring native script for ElasticSearch.

My script class is extending the AbstractFloatSearchScript abstract class.

Everything is working fine; however, I'm wondering if it's possible, in my scoring method, to get the maximum value in elasticsearch for a particular field(these are integer values).

I want the max value to assist me in my custom scoring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Max Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_metrics_aggregations.html#java-aggs-metrics-max) to get that data.

Comment: I'm not sure I can use this in a scoring function though. Also, I'm using the plugin API, not the Java client API.